# UWP unclickable transparent overlay

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to make a UWP app with Overlay function like below link.

Overlays on other program, transparent, and unclick-able window (Only lock button is click-able).

[Image](https://postimg.cc/9r6BdFWr)

I've tried [CompactOverlay](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/) but it can't be transparent nor unclick-able.

.

How could I make this feature with UWP app.

This is a examples link btw. [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9MXQM7VPRSNT)

Comment: NVM this guy didn't make it with UWP. Its electron.

Comment: Hello, UWP does not currently provide the API for the custom background that you need to be transparent. You can use electron or other win32 way to develop and then convert to UWP application.